# Windows Desktop Flutter: Error when using flutter libserialport package

Tags: windows, flutter, serial-port

I am trying to convert an existing Qt application to Flutter App. The existing application communicates with a hardware over serial port. Sends and receives commands and messages.

I am using flutter's libserialport package to achieve the communication.

The application UI has a simple button as of now which calls following function when clicked.

```
void displayPorts()
{
  _name = SerialPort.availablePorts;
  print(_name);
  sp = SerialPort(_name[2]);
  sp.config.baudRate = 9600;
  sp.config.bits = 8;
  sp.config.stopBits = 1;
  sp.config.parity = 0;
  sp.config.xonXoff = 0;
  sp.config.setFlowControl(0);
  sp.config.dtr = 0;
  sp.config.rts = 0;
  sp.open(mode: 3);
  if(!sp.openReadWrite()){
    print(SerialPort.lastError);
  }
  if(sp.isOpen){
    print("open and write");
    sp.write(utf8.encode("A"));
  }

  print('DN: ${sp.deviceNumber}'); 
  print('\tDescription: ${sp.description}');
  print('\tManufacturer: ${sp.manufacturer}');

}
if(sp.isOpen){
    print("open and write");
    sp.write(utf8.encode("A"));
  }
```

I am getting following error on running this:
"flutter: SerialPortError: Access is denied., errno = 5"

The application is able to read available ports and display the information as per print messages above.

But it is not able to read/write on the port(The print statement inside if check of isOpen is not printed). I have also attached an oscilloscope on the output of USB/Serial converter and can not any message being thrown out.

Any pointers to possible solution. I am running the application from a user login with admin rights. I did not get any relevant links on google search.

Comment: I was able to get the code sending data over serial port without the access error. The issue turned out to be serial port already open from the same code from previous run. I was not closing the port when the app was being closed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencied the same problem and i realize the problem was the port had been used for other program (In my case Arduino IDE serial monitor).